# How to validate JPA schema so that it matches the real database schema

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hopefully i won't misuse any technical term.

We have a DB2 schema with many tables which we will connect with the appropriate connections (one-to-many, many-to-many etc) in the next days.

The goal is to make this exact schema in the Java side using Spring JPA. We want to validate the schema created using the Spring JPA so that it matches the database schema.

I'm using the following property
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` and it seems to work only in one direction, that is, it checks if the database schema satisfies the Jpa schema. It doesn't seem to work the other way around: the database schema has tables that are not defined in the Java side and the application can run successfully.

Can we somehow validate the Jpa schema so that it matches the database schema absolutely?

Comment: I doubt its possible and also there is not really any use case. Your application can still run, even if you have tables that are not mapped

Comment: It seems that you need a checksum, computing over all database tables parameters and comparison on JAVA side. Other option would be to use Liquibase-based migrations

Comment: Doing so would prevent your application from running on an updated schema - which would really hinder future upgrades. Schema updates, depending on the database and the updates, can be done while an application is running (zero downtime) in advance of the application changes that might rely on the schema changes. The ORM validation just needs to validate that it can use the schema, why bother if there is more there it cannot and does not need to see?